# chapter 2 problem B 27: frank jones lebesgue integration on euclidean spaces

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

> prove that $$\lambda^{*}(A) = \inf \Big\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda(I_k) \Big| A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k \Big\}$$

It suffices to show that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists (I_k) \text{ and  }A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k  \text{ s.t }  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda (I_k)  - \epsilon < \lambda^{*}(A) $$

note that outer measure is defined as follows

$$\lambda^{*}(A) = \inf_{A \subset G : \text{G is open}} \lambda(G)$$

so given $\epsilon,$  there exists $A \subset G$ s.t $\lambda(G) - \epsilon < \lambda^{*}(A)$

now use following property

> every nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be expressed as a countable union of nonoverlapping axis rectangles, i.e.,$G  = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k$ where $I_k$ are axis aligned rectangles.

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda(I_k) - \epsilon = \lambda(G) - \epsilon    < \lambda^*(A)$ so, we are done.

Comment: It would help if you would define $\lambda$ and $\lambda^*$

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @AnginaSeng [tag:solution-verification]

Comment: Also the property at the end isn't true as stated. The correct statement is that "every non-empty open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ can be expressed as a countable union of disjoint axis rectangles, up to a set of measure zero" (if you allow for half-closed, half-open rectangles like $n$-fold products of $[a,b)$, then you can express every open set as a countable disjoint union of such half-closed axis-aligned rectangles)

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes! . You are right!. I haven't given careful thought.